# How to pass values dynamically inside API Body using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, databricks

```
doc_number
3
2
1
34
4
7
```

Python code:

```
z = {
    "selections": []
}

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    z['selections'].append({"trans_id":''})
    z['selections'][index]["trans_id"] = row['_doc_number']
    
print(z)
```

Output:

```
{'selections': [{'trans_id': 3}, {'trans_id': 2}, {'trans_id': 1}, {'trans_id': 34}, 
{'trans_id': 4},{'trans_id': 7}]}
```

Excepted Output:

```
{"selections": ["trans_id/3", "trans_id/2", "trans_id/1", "trans_id/34", "trans_id/4",
 "trans_id/7"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but something like this should work:

```
z = {'selections': [f'trans_id/{doc_number}' for doc_number in df['doc_number']]}
```

Or maybe:

```
z = {'selections': df['doc_number'].astype(str).radd('trans_id/').tolist()}
```